# Is vote counted if a post is deleted?

Tags: support, voting, deletion, statistics

On your user profile, there is a vote count.

I am just curious about this:

If you give a vote on a post and the post is deleted, does it decrease your count? (This effect certain badges)

The reason I ask this is because I thought the votes are 'locked' with posts. When posts are deleted by the author, the posts are merely hidden so your votes are still there - is my guess correct?

Also, what happens if the posts is deleted by a moderator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different vote counts  on your profile: public (on `summary` tab) and private (on `votes` tab). Votes on deleted posts:

- are included in the public count
- are counted toward the badges.

It makes no difference who deleted the post. See  ["Votes cast" should include votes on deleted contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117846)

The private count behaves differently because it shows you itemized votes with links to the posts. If the posts on which you voted are deleted, the system will hide them from you and as a result, will usually show you a smaller total of votes than on the public count. It is not obvious what the correct behavior should be, since access to deleted posts varies by reputation, etc. There is a current feature request  [Don't hide (un)deletion votes cast on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140328) with Shog9's comment dated from yesterday:

> we actually had this on the list to implement at one time, and somehow it morphed into [something else]  instead. I blame high levels of gamma radiation.

I actually like the fact that by taking the difference of two counts, I know how many posts I voted on got deleted.

Comment: thanks and lol about 'I know how many posts I voted on got deleted'...

Answer (score 2):

Good question, and one I hadn't really considered. [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) on Mathematica says that your vote count is not affected, but it does give you back that vote for the day.

Comment: and  what is rm-rf?

Comment: @Lost1: I've added a link to their profile

Comment: @Lost1 Type it into the command line of your Linux system to find out.

Comment: @Lost1: or don't :-)

Comment: @Lost1 Essentially: $\textbf{R}\text{e}\textbf{m}\text{ove -}\textbf{r}\text{ecursive }\textbf{f}\text{older}$